# Restrict model entries to author

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

I have model where users add organizations, how can restrict their access to only organizations created by the user? (restriction include view and edit).

Example:

> User1 add Organization1
>
> User2 add Organization2
>
> User1 must see and edit only Organization1
>
> User2 must see and edit only Organization2

models.py

```
class Organization (models.Model):
    enumerator_name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

admin.py

```
class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.enumerator_name = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, not sure if it's the correct way, but it works just as i wanted.

```
class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.enumerator_name = request.user
        obj.save()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        method = getattr(
            super(PeopleAdmin, self), 'get_queryset',
            getattr(super(PeopleAdmin, self), 'queryset', None))
        qs = method(request)
        return qs.filter(enumerator_name=request.user)
```